# Failure to link CSS and images when rendering a pug template using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

When I want to display the result of an HTTP Post request for a form for Email verification through OTP, I use `res.render('index',{<var_name: <message to display>})`. But this does not link the CSS which I used for the corresponding template in style.css file, nor is it able to access the images in the public folder. The message which I transmit is also not displayed on the resulting page. Why is this happening? Since the index.pug file is my homepage template, so when I first start the server the template is rendered correctly with proper CSS and images but not when it is rendered after the request is processed.

My main aim here is to take the email from the user through a form, send the form data to the request handler to verify if the email exists in the database and if it exists, send an email to the user on that email id containing an OTP for login.

Directory structure-

```
bin
|
models
|
node_modules
|
public----
|        |images
|        |javascripts
|        |stylesheets--style.css
|
routes----
|         |index.js
|         |login.js
|
views----index.pug
|
app.js
|
controller.js
|
config.js
|
package.json
|
package-lock.json
```

Code snippet of route handler in *login.js* file in routes folder-

```
const express = require('express');
const loginRouter = express.Router();

const controller = require('../controller');

loginRouter.post('/email',controller.verify_email);

loginRouter.post('/otp',controller.verify_otp);

module.exports = loginRouter;
```

Code snippet of *verify_email* controller in the *controller.js* file-

```
exports.verify_email = [
    //validate and sanitize the email field
    body('email','Email Required').trim().isLength({ min:1 }).escape(),

    //Process request after validation and sanitization
    (req,res,next) => {
        //Extract the validation errors from the request
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.render('index.pug',{ errormessage: 'Please enter correct Email ID' })
        }
        else {
            Student.findOne({'email': req.body.email})       
            .then((user) => {
                if(user != null) {
                    //Send OTP
                    var digits = '0123456789';
                    var otplength = 5;
                    var otp = '';
                    for(i=1; i<=otplength; i++) {
                        otp += Math.trunc(Math.random()*(digits.length));
                    }
                    
                    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                        service: 'gmail',
                        auth: {
                          user: 'sender@gmail.com',  //ENTER CREDENTIALS
                          pass: 'x-x-x-x'
                        }
                    });
                      
                    var mailOptions = {
                        from: 'sender@gmail.com',
                        to: req.body.email,       //HAVE TO INCLUDE THE EMAIL OF USER IN THE REQUEST PROPERTY
                        subject: 'OTP Verification',
                        html: `<h3>Enter the following OTP for login: <strong>${otp}</strong></h3>`          //HAVE TO SEND OTP
                    };
                      
                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
                        if (error) {
                          console.log(error);
                        } else {
                          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    res.render('index',{ errormessage: 'Email ID not found in student database.' })
                }
            }, (err) => next(err)).catch((err) => next(err));
        }
    }
];
```

Relevant snippet in the *index.pug* file-

```
doctype html
head
  // Required meta tags always come first
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
  meta(http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='ie=edge')
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p' crossorigin='anonymous')
  // Bootstrap CSS
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l' crossorigin='anonymous')
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css')
  title Resources
if  errormessage
  myfunction(errormessage)
script.
  function myfunction(errormessage) {
  alert(errormessage)
  }
```

Please help me with this. I have been trying to find out the solution for days without much help. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Am I right that at `if (user != null)` your code does not perform any rendering or complete the request with a proper response? It merely sends an email. The user's browser should be left hanging with an `x`. – Old Geezer 4 hours ago

Comment: @OldGeezer I think I have a hint what you are trying to say. You mean to say that I haven't provided any response to the user on the browser after the email has been sent, right? So the user is left hanging. But still, if the user != null, and the email code has been executed, why don't I receive any email when I do slight modification in the email addresses and put my email in the database and then try to login ?

Comment: Email is not a good test. First you have to prove that your email as coded is working. No email received could easily mean that `user == null`! Put in `console.log` statements to verify the code flow at each step.